# Magento - Assign attributes to categories in layered navigation

Tags: php, magento, attributes, categories, layered-navigation

I've been working with Magento for a few months now. I have a Products category with 7 sub-categories. These categories are various brands with sub-categories of types of products. I'm looking to add certain attributes to each of these brand's products individually.

For example, in 'Brand 1' there is 'Types of Drawers' attribute of: 2 Drawer, 4 Drawer. There are others I need to sort by according to what category it is in.

The problem is that Magento doesn't seem to do this natively. That attribute, 'Types of Drawers' is showing up on every page previous to the specific brand page that it applies to. The scope is too large on these attributes.

I've already purchased and downloaded [Advanced Navigation](http://www.gomage.com/extensions/gomage-advanced-navigation.html) from GoMage, but that doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Why is this not part of Magento and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes available to filter are populated depending on what products are visible on that category page. Without modifying the functionality, all I can think of is to set the Products category 'Is Anchor' to be 'No' and display the subcategories instead but that may not be what you want to do.