# Magento category and attributes

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

In Magento Community Ed., my structure of products is such that there are a set of 100 attributes that some products are assigned to and some are not. These attributes values are common to all products. So if Product A has attribute X with value 360, if Product B has that attribute, its value will also be 360. Now these attribute values would need to be updated every hour or so. Is there a way that I can update these at the back end in one csv/excel file and the changes apply to all products that have subscribed to this attribute?

Also, is there a way to create attributes for categories ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create and use your own import in Magento.  You find the module using System Menu ~ Import/Export ~ Import.

Oh, and refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269144/magento-assign-attributes-to-categories-in-layered-navigation) for Attributes on a Category
Good luck!